# Multiple microservice trying to create amazonaws bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create S3 bucket using createBucket(String bucketName) method of AmazonS3Client Class (com.amazonaws) but in documentation provided here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/ it doesn't mention what would be the scenario if my 2 microservices try to create same bucket at same time. Will it throw error if one is creating the bucket and other calls get at same time.
Exceptions throw are also not clear about this scenario.

```
public Bucket createBucket(CreateBucketRequest createBucketRequest)
                throws SdkClientException,
                       AmazonServiceException
```

I am using following version of s3 sdk

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.184</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why not just try it in code?  Create the bucket twice and see what happens.

Comment: @stdunbar It is not exactly same to creating bucket twice, I am talking about the scenario where one thread is in process of creating bucket and if other thread also tries to make from another instance of microservice.Then what would happen. If it would be one thread only then simply I would have check by doesBucketExist() method.

Comment: Its just like when we use double lock checking in singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

According to [these API](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#createBucket--) docs the Method Signature looks different:

```java
default CreateBucketResponse createBucket(CreateBucketRequest createBucketRequest)
                                   throws BucketAlreadyExistsException,
                                          BucketAlreadyOwnedByYouException,
                                          AwsServiceException,
                                          SdkClientException,
                                          S3Exception
```

You should see the `BucketAlreadyExistsException`.

Are you using the old SDK (v1)?

In general the AWS API handles these conflicts by rejecting the second API call and returning an error that's denoted by the 409 conflict HTTP status code and is called "BucketAlreadyExists". You can learn more about that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList).

Comment: I think both are different, the one I am using in my pom is different, I have updated question with the version of sdk. Also the file I am using is com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client whose createBucket method doesn't throws BucketAlreadyExistsException exception